# iOS layouts for a beginner

Tags: ios, swift

So I consider myself a relatively bright person, not genius but not moron but I cannot seem to understand even the basic layout principles of iOS and wondered if someone may be able to point me to something that would help.

Specifically I am working on a storyboard on a view with an ImageView and a CollectionView. I have tried to get the image as a header but every single tutorial that I have tried doesn't seem to work (a problem that I have seen recurring with iOS development).

So I put the imageview with constraints at the top, left and right so that it sits in the middle at the top. The problem that I have is that when I put the collection view underneath the image, it either dissappears (most of the time if I add ANY constraints) or it sits over the top of or beneath (as in behind) the ImageView. Is there any concept of relative constraints? Why is this so hard in iOS? IS there a working tutorial that doesn't require me hand coding the layouts? Is it better for me just to hand code the layouts as the storyboard is the biggest time sink I've ever seen?

Your thoughts and help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work. Try this (I tried and both the imageView and collection view show):

[image: Demo 1]
[image: Demo 2]

What I did:

- Add UIImageView with top, left and right constraints;
- Add height constraint to image view;
- Add collection view with bottom, left and right constraints;
- Add top constraint to collection view relative to uiimageview top + uiimageview height.

Result:

[image]

Comment: cool, I agree that it should just work, I just seem to have found that nothing that should work does (I literally have to swear till it works on every change to the code at present). Could you go into that last step, how do I add a relative constraint?

Comment: Hold ctrl, click on the collection view and drag to the uiimageview. A popup occurs where you can select 'top'.

Comment: Cheers that's great. I honestly don't know how people cope with iOS dev but I'm determined to continue even if I go skint in swear jar expenses

Comment: It really isn't that hard. Read a lot about the principles behind it (Apple documentation and stuff), instead of only copying code from tutorials. It helps understanding why things work the way they do. Good luck with your app!

Comment: I've been through a lot of the documentation already, I will continue to do so, I kind of understand a lot of the rudimentary things already (and swift certainly helps from a c based background) but little magic things that happen in the IDE (like ctrl dragging seems a popular one) just require knowing.

Comment: That's true. You can get more info about it by looking at the WWDC session video's about Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/